# "Fatal error: Call to undefined function " Error

Tags: php, fatal-error

The following error :

```
  Fatal error: Call to undefined function add() in E:\xampp\htdocs\paperblog\Admin\AddNewPost.php on line 18
```

line 18 :

```
 $msg=add($title,$subtitle,$details,$_FILES['_postImage']);
```

The whole codes (`HTML`
,`PHP`)are in the following lines.

I've 4 files:

1. The `AddNewPost.php` file is the main file has the `HTML` code.

   - Has `PHP` code :

   > ```
   >  <?php
   >   include_once("..\DB.php");
   >   include_once("..\Classes\post.php");
   >
   >   $title="";
   >   $subtitle="";
   >   $details="";
   >   $msg="";
   >
   >   if(isset($_POST['_PostSubmit']))
   >   {
   >           $title=$_POST['_PostTitle'];
   >           $subtitle=$_POST['_PostSubTtile'];
   >           $details=$_POST['_PostDetails'];
   >
   >           if(  !empty($title)||!empty($subtitle)||!empty($details) )
   >                           {
   >             $msg=add($title,$subtitle,$details,$_FILES['_postImage']);
   >
   >                           }
   >          else
   >                $msg=" The post is empty ";
   >
   >   }
   >
   >
   >
   >   include_once("Header.php");
   > ?>
   > ```

   - And `HTML`:

   > ```
   >    <form action="AddNewPost.php" method="post" id="cmntfrm" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
   >
   >          <P align="center" style="color:#F00"><?=$msg?></P>
   >          <p>&nbsp; </p>
   >
   >           <table width="600" border="0" align="center">
   >                    <img src="../images/addNewPost.png"/>
   >                     <br />
   >                     <br />
   >
   >                   <tr>
   >                         <td width="131">Post Title <h8 style="color:#F00">*</h8>:</td>
   >                         <td width="443"><input name="_PostTitle" type="text" /></td>
   >
   >                   </tr>
   >                   <tr>
   >                         <td>Post Sub Title <h8 style="color:#F00">*</h8>:</td>
   >                         <td><input name="_PostSubTtile" type="text" /></td>
   >
   >                   </tr>
   >                   <tr>
   >                         <td>Post Details :</td>
   >                         <td><textarea name="_PostDetails" cols="32" rows="7">&nbsp;</textarea></td>
   >
   >                   </tr>
   >                   <tr>
   >                         <td>Post Image :</td>
   >                         <td><input name="_postImage" type="file"/></td>
   >                   </tr>
   >                   <tr>
   >                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
   >                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
   >                   </tr>
   >                   <tr>
   >                         <td></td>
   >                         <td><input name="_PostSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" id="submit" /></td>
   >                   </tr>
   >         </table>
   >         <center>
   >                <img src="../Post_Imges/a.jpg" height="420" width="460" />
   >         </center>
   > ```

---

2. The`post.php` file which has functions of the post form  where is in  the classes folder. It Has `PHP` code:

   > ```
   >    <?php 
   > include_once("../DB.php");
   >
   > class post{
   >
   >   var $Post_ID;
   >   var $title,$subtitle,$postdetail,$Post_Imgs;
   >   var $pmonth ,$pyear ,$pday;
   >
   >
   >
   >
   > function add($title,$subtitle,$postdetail,$file){
   >         $query=" insert into post(Title,SubTitle,PostDetails,PDay,PMonth,PYear)
   >                              values('$title,'$subtitle','$postdetail'".date("d").",".date("m").",".date("Y").")";
   >         $this->Post_ID=$this->GetLastPostId();
   >         $msg=test("Add",$query);
   >         $msg.="<br/>".$this->uploadImage($file);
   >         return $msg;    
   >
   >       }
   >
   >
   > function GetLastPostId(){
   >           $query="select Max(Post_ID) from Post";
   >           $result=mysql_query($query);
   >           $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
   >           return $row[0];
   >
   >           }
   >
   > function uploadImage($file){
   >       uploadFile("Post_Imges\$Post_ID.jpg",$file);
   >
   >       }
   > } 
   > ?>
   > ```

---

3.The `DB.php` file which has some function for DB. It has :

```
     <?php
        include_once("functions.php");

                    mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
                    mysql_select_db("paperbloge");

                    function test($test ,$query){

                    mysql_query($query);
                    if(!empty(mysql_errno()))
                                                  return "Post ".$test." Successfully" ;
                                       else
                                                  return "Error".mysql_errno().":".mysql_error();


                }


?>
```

---

4. Finaly, `functions.php`file which has uploadfile function.

   ```
           function uploadFile($folderPathFileName,$file){

                 if (!empty($file['tmp_name'])){

                                  move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\paperblog\ ".$folderFileName);
                                                 $msg.="<br/> Image uploaded Successfully";                
                                             }
                else 
                                                 $msg= "Image File too large or No Image File";
                return $msg;       

               }
   ?>
   ```

---

Thats the whole codes that i've .

Does anyone know what is wrong here that cause this problem?

Thanks

---

Ya it's working , But have some errors again .
Thanks for your helping .

Comment: `add` function is under `post` class and you need to instantiate the class before calling the function something as `$post = new post(); $post->add()`

Comment: hhhhh I got some errors too after it works

Comment: What errors @Norhan?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i added one of them untill i solve other by myself. If i don't, I'll add them here

Comment: They should be asked in a new question, as your initial question has been solved, IMO.

Comment: ok, I'll ask them in a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add()` is *not* a function. It is a method of a class called "post". That means you have to instantiate that class and then call that method:

```
$post = new Post();
$msg=$post->add($title,$subtitle,$details,$_FILES['_postImage']);
```

Answer (score 1):

`add` is part of the class `post`

Change your line to;

```
$objPost = new post();
$msg = $objPost->add($title,$subtitle,$details,$_FILES['_postImage']);
```